# Why does the iterator print different output (related to failsafe)?

Tags: java, iterator

Why does the iterator print different output (related to failsafe)?

```
public class failSafe {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Map<Integer,Integer> student = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    //Defining a new HashMap
     student.put(3, 5);
     student.put(2,10);
     Iterator<Integer> itr = student.keySet().iterator();

  while(itr.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(student.get(itr.next()));
       //student.put(4,40); will print 40 also
       student.put(1,89);
      //will not print 89.
   }

`` }

}
```

Comment: why it should print 89?

Comment: @AR.3 Ah! My bad. This is what happens when you just read half the content. :)

Answer (score 3):

The iterator of a `ConcurrentHashMap` is not fail-safe. It is [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly). It guarantees to act on the snapshot of elements at the moment of its creation as the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) states:

> Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration.

It does not guarantee reflecting newly added elements after its creation.

Comment: Ok, so here is the catch : got it : "at some point at or since the creation"..Thanks